# How to show the reply concept inside div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to develop the internal mail concept on my page using HTML, CSS and Javascript or JQuery. Actually, I have finished the Inbox, Outbox and Sent Item functionality. At present, I am working on the Reply functionality, but have encountered some problems (outlined below).

I want to to insert data into the database with the following format:
    ----Original Message----
    From : test@test.com
    To : test1@test.com
    Subject : test

And, whenever I want to retrieve that data from the database, I want it to return a same format.But now it's return the following format.

```
----Original Message----From : test@test.comTo : test1@test.comSubject : test
```

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this? Please help me....
Thanks in advance...

Comment: @jrd1 aww, you broke the formatting again ^^

Comment: @nijansen, trust me, it wasn't intentional! The previous one was broken too. Something is weird with the editor, or how it is parsed. :|

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n (NewLine)`  if text or `<br/>`  if HTML to break the message into multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this question.
Actually, I insert the data into the `db` to replace the `<br>` into `\n` using the following code:

```
body = body.split("<br>").join("\r\n");
```

Then, when I retrieve that data from `db` using the following code,

```
body = body.split("\n").join("<br />");
```

Now it's working fine.